# Vetor Inicializado mas Nulo

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Estou a dar em doidos, com um pedaço de código simples.
A minha aplicação, serve para dar informação a utilizar sobre um percurso.

Eu adiciono várias cidades, e depois tento adicionar ao vetor, mas no final o vetor encontra-se sempre nulo.

Eis o código:

```
 Ponto_Turistico Santo_Tirso = new Ponto_Turistico("Santo Tirso");
 Ponto_Turistico Felgueiras = new Ponto_Turistico("Felgueiras");


adPontoTuristico((T) Santo_Tirso);
adPontoTuristico((T) Felgueiras);
```

**Método addPontoTuristico:**

ERRO na Linha:

> if (this.cont_cid == this.pontosTuristicos_roteiro.length) {

```
public void adPontoTuristico(T pontoT) {

    Ponto_Turistico c = (Ponto_Turistico) pontoT;


        if (this.cont_cid == this.pontosTuristicos_roteiro.length) {
            expandCapacity_PT();
        }
        this.pontosTuristicos_roteiro[this.cont_cid] = c;
        this.cont_cid++;


}
```

**EDIT CLASSE ROTEIROS**

```
public class Roteiros<T> {

    private final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 20;
    private Ponto_Turistico[] pontosTuristicos_roteiro;
    private int cont_cid;

    /**
     *
     */
    public void Roteiros() {

        this.pontosTuristicos_roteiro = new Ponto_Turistico[DEFAULT_SIZE];
        this.cont_cid = 0;

    }

    /**
     * Adiciona um ponto turistico
     *
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void AdicionarPonto_Turistico() throws IOException {

        System.out.println("**Adicionar um Ponto_Turistico**");
        System.out.println("Nome do novo Ponto Turistico:");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String opc = br.readLine();

        if (procurarPontoTuris((T) opc) != null) { // se o ponto turistico que o jogador adicionar  for diferente  de null, ou seja se ainda nao existir

            Ponto_Turistico nova_city = new Ponto_Turistico(opc);
            adPontoTuristico((T) nova_city);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Já existe um ponto turistico com o nome escolhido!");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adiciona um Ponto Turistico
     *
     * @param pontoT a adicionar
     * @return 
     */
    public void adPontoTuristico(T pontoT) {

        Ponto_Turistico c = (Ponto_Turistico) pontoT;


            if (this.cont_cid == this.pontosTuristicos_roteiro.length) {
                expandCapacity_PT();
            }
            this.pontosTuristicos_roteiro[this.cont_cid] = c;
            this.cont_cid++;




    }

    public void removerPontoTuristico() throws IOException {

        System.out.println("\n **Remover Ponto Turistico**");
        System.out.println("\n Introduza o ponto turistico a ser removido:");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String opc2 = br.readLine();

        Ponto_Turistico pro = procurarPontoTuris((T) opc2);
        if (pro != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.cont_cid; i++) {
                if (this.pontosTuristicos_roteiro[i].getNome().equals(opc2)) {

                    this.pontosTuristicos_roteiro[i] = null;
                    this.cont_cid--;
                } else {
                    this.pontosTuristicos_roteiro[i] = this.pontosTuristicos_roteiro[i + 1];
                    this.cont_cid--;
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Ponto Turistico: " + opc2 + " nao encontrada!");
        }

    }

    /**
     * Iniciar um jogo
     *
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws EmptyCollectionException
     */
    public void iniciar() throws IOException, EmptyCollectionException {
        String a;

        do {
            System.out.println("Agência de Viagens");
            System.out.println("1- Percursos Existentes");
            System.out.println("2- Administracao");
            System.out.println("3- Sair");

            System.out.print("A sua escolha: ");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String opc = br.readLine();
            a = opc;
            System.out.println(" ");

            switch (opc) {
                case "1":
                    menuJogar();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    admin();
                    break;
            }

        } while (!a.equals("3"));

    }

    /**
     * Menu administrador
     *
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void admin() throws IOException {
        String o;
        do {
            System.out.println("\n\nMenu Administrador");
            System.out.println("1- Adicionar Ponto Turistico");
            System.out.println("2- Remover Ponto_Turistico");
            System.out.println("3- Alterar Trajetos entre Pontos");
            System.out.println("4- Adicionar Trajetos Entre Pontos");
            System.out.println("5- Listar Pontos Turisticos");
            System.out.println("6- Listar Trajetos");
            System.out.println("7- Sair");
            System.out.print("A sua escolha: ");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String opc = br.readLine();
            o = opc;

            switch (opc) {
                case "1":
                    AdicionarPonto_Turistico(); // adiciona um novo ponto turistico
                    break;
                case "2":
                    removerPontoTuristico(); // remove um ponto turistico já existente
                    break;
                case "3":
                    System.out.println("\nAlterar Trajetos entre Pontos ");
                    System.out.print("Nome do Ponto Turistico a ser alterado:");
                    String nome = br.readLine();
                    Ponto_Turistico proc = procurarPontoTuris((T) nome);
                    if (proc != null) {
                        int pos = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < this.cont_cid; i++) {
                            if (this.pontosTuristicos_roteiro[i].getNome().equals(nome)) {
                                pos = i;
                            }
                        }

                        System.out.println("\nINTRODUZA OS VALORES ANTIGOS!");
                        System.out.print("Distancia Total: ");
                        double old_dist = 0;
                        String ond_d = br.readLine();
                        old_dist = Double.parseDouble(ond_d);
                        System.out.print("\nDuracao Total: ");
                        double old_durac = 0;
                        String ond_dura = br.readLine();
                        old_durac = Double.parseDouble(ond_dura);
                        System.out.print("\nCusto Total: ");
                        double old_custo = 0;
                        String ond_cust = br.readLine();
                        old_custo = Double.parseDouble(ond_cust);
                        System.out.print("\nPonto Turistico Final: ");
                        String ond_city = br.readLine();

                        Trajeto[] old_traj = this.pontosTuristicos_roteiro[pos].getAdjacencias();

                        for (int j = 0; j < (this.pontosTuristicos_roteiro[pos].getNum_cidades() * 2); j++) {
                            if ((old_traj[j].getCidade_final().getNome().equals(ond_city)) && (old_traj[j].getDistancia() == old_dist) && (old_traj[j].getDuracao() == old_durac) && (old_traj[j].getCusto() == old_custo)) {
                                System.out.println("\nINTRODUZA NOVOS VALORES!");
                                System.out.print("Distancia: ");
                                double new_dist = 0;
                                String new_d = br.readLine();
                                new_dist = Double.parseDouble(new_d);
                                System.out.print("\nDuracao: ");
                                double new_durac = 0;
                                String new_dura = br.readLine();
                                new_durac = Double.parseDouble(new_dura);
                                System.out.print("\nCusto: ");
                                double new_custo = 0;
                                String new_cust = br.readLine();
                                new_custo = Double.parseDouble(new_cust);
                                System.out.print("\nCidade Destino: ");
                                String new_city = br.readLine();
                                if (procurarPontoTuris((T) new_city) != null) {
                                    Trajeto traje = new Trajeto(procurarPontoTuris((T) new_city), new_dist, new_durac, new_custo);
                                    this.pontosTuristicos_roteiro[pos].alterarTrajeto(pos, traje);
                                } else {
                                    System.out.println("Não foi encontrado nenhum ponto turistico com o nome " + new_city + "\n");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Ponto Turistico  não encontrado!\n");
                    }

                    break;
                case "4":
                    System.out.println("\n**Adicionar Trajetos ao Ponto Turistico**");
                    System.out.print("Indique a cidade à qual quer adicionar: ");
                    String city = br.readLine();
                    Ponto_Turistico proc2 = procurarPontoTuris((T) city);

                    if (proc2 != null) {
                        int pos1 = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < this.cont_cid; i++) {
                            if (this.pontosTuristicos_roteiro[i].getNome().equals(city)) {
                                pos1 = i;
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.println("\nINTRODUZA NOVOS VALORES!");
                        System.out.print("Distancia Total: ");
                        double new_dist = 0;
                        String new_d = br.readLine();
                        new_dist = Double.parseDouble(new_d);
                        System.out.print("\nDuracao Total: ");
                        double new_durac = 0;
                        String new_dura = br.readLine();
                        new_durac = Double.parseDouble(new_dura);
                        System.out.print("\nCusto Total: ");
                        double new_custo = 0;
                        String new_cust = br.readLine();
                        new_custo = Double.parseDouble(new_cust);
                        System.out.print("\nPonto Turistico de Destino: ");
                        String ncity = br.readLine();
                        Ponto_Turistico g = procurarPontoTuris((T) ncity);
                        if (g != null) {
                            this.pontosTuristicos_roteiro[pos1].adicionar_trajeto(g, new_dist, new_durac, new_custo);
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Ponto Turistico de  destino nao encontrado!");
                        }

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Ponto Turistico " + city + " não encontrado!");
                    }
                    break;

                case "6":
                    System.out.println("Pontos Turisticos Existentes");
                    for (int k = 0; k < this.cont_cid; k++) {
                        System.out.println(k + 1 + "- " + this.pontosTuristicos_roteiro[k].getNome());
                    }
                    break;
                case "7":
                    System.out.println("** Trajetos Existentes a partir da cidade **");
                    System.out.println("Introduza o Ponto Turistico a ver: ");
                    String l_ci = br.readLine();
                    Ponto_Turistico v = procurarPontoTuris((T) l_ci);
                    Trajeto[] t = v.getAdjacencias();

                    System.out.println("\n\n\nTrajetos:");
                    for (int ta = 0; ta < v.getNum_cidades(); ta++) {
                        System.out.println((ta + 1) + "- " + t[ta].getCidade_final() + " dista: " + t[ta].getDistancia() + " Custo: " + t[ta].getCusto() + " Duracao: " + t[ta].getDuracao());
                    }
                    break;
            }
        } while (!o.equals("8"));

    }

    /**
     * Menu Secundario
     *
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws EmptyCollectionException
     */
    public void menuJogar() throws IOException, EmptyCollectionException {
        String a;
        do {
            System.out.println("Menu de Viagens");
            System.out.println("1- Nova Viagem");
            System.out.println("2- Sair");

            System.out.print("A sua escolha: ");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String opc = br.readLine();
            a = opc;
            System.out.println(" ");

            switch (opc) {
                case "1":
                    menuNovaViagem();
                    break;

            }
        } while (!a.equals("3"));
    }

    /**
     * Procurar pontos turisticos
     *
     * @param nome nome do ponto turistico
     * @return ponto turistico
     */
    public Ponto_Turistico procurarPontoTuris(T nome) {

        String nome_pontoTuris = (String) nome;

        for (int i = 0; i < this.cont_cid; i++) {
            if (this.pontosTuristicos_roteiro[i].getNome().equals(nome_pontoTuris)) {
                return this.pontosTuristicos_roteiro[i];
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Menu novaViagem
     *
     *
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws EmptyCollectionException
     */
    public void menuNovaViagem() throws IOException, EmptyCollectionException {
        Percursos_SelfService percursoSelf = new Percursos_SelfService();
        String a;
        do {
            System.out.println("\n\n");
            System.out.println("O que deseja fazer:");
            System.out.println("1- Self Service Percurso");
            System.out.println("2- Ver Pontos Turisticos mais Atraentes");
            System.out.println("3- Procurar Percurso de uma Cidade");
            System.out.println("4- Sair");

            System.out.print("A sua escolha: ");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String opc = br.readLine();
            a = opc;
            System.out.println(" ");

            switch (opc) {
                case "1":
                    percursoSelf.verPercursosMaisEconomicos();

                    /*  String opc2 = br.readLine();
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    Cidade target = procurarCidade((T) opc2);
                    if (target != null && !j.containsCidade(target)) {
                        j.conquistarCidade(target);
                    } else if (j.containsCidade(target)) {
                        System.out.println("Cidade já conquistada!");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Cidade nao encontrada!"); */
                    break;

                case "2":
                    System.out.println("Os nossos pontos de turismo");
                    for (int i = 0; i < this.cont_cid; i++) {
                        System.out.println(this.pontosTuristicos_roteiro[i].getNome());

                    }
                    break;
                case "3":
                    /*
                    System.out.print("Alterar para a cidade: ");
                    String b = br.readLine();
                    Cidade cti = procurarCidade((T) b);
                    if (j.containsCidade(cti)) {
                        j.setCidade_atual(cti);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Ainda nao conquistou " + cti.getNome());
                    }
                     */
                    break;

            }
        } while (!a.equals("4"));
    }

    /**
     * Carrega informação Esta função é uma alternativa pouco eficiente, na
     * tentativa de superar a falha nos ficheiros
     */
    public void carregarinfo() {

        Ponto_Turistico Santo_Tirso = new Ponto_Turistico("Santo Tirso");
        Ponto_Turistico Felgueiras = new Ponto_Turistico("Felgueiras");
        Ponto_Turistico Amarante = new Ponto_Turistico("Amarante");
        Ponto_Turistico Celorico_de_Basto = new Ponto_Turistico("Celorico de Basto");
        Ponto_Turistico Fafe = new Ponto_Turistico("Fafe");
        Ponto_Turistico Guimaraes = new Ponto_Turistico("Guimarães");
        Ponto_Turistico Mondim_Basto = new Ponto_Turistico("Mondim de Basto");
        Ponto_Turistico Famalicao = new Ponto_Turistico("VN Famalicão");

        Santo_Tirso.adicionar_trajeto(Felgueiras, 29.0, 41.0, 2.50);
        Santo_Tirso.adicionar_trajeto(Mondim_Basto, 63, 48, 2.2);
        Santo_Tirso.adicionar_trajeto(Famalicao, 11, 20, 3.5);
        Amarante.adicionar_trajeto(Famalicao, 12, 25, 4.5);




        adPontoTuristico((T) Santo_Tirso);
        adPontoTuristico((T) Felgueiras);



    }

    /**
     * Expande a capacidade de pontos turisticos
     *
     * @return
     */
    private Ponto_Turistico[] expandCapacity_PT() {

        Ponto_Turistico[] novo = new Ponto_Turistico[this.pontosTuristicos_roteiro.length + this.DEFAULT_SIZE];
        System.arraycopy(novo, this.cont_cid, this.pontosTuristicos_roteiro, 0, this.cont_cid);
        return novo;
    }

}
```

**EDIT - CLASSE PONTO_TURISTICO**

```
public class Ponto_Turistico<T> implements Comparable<Ponto_Turistico> {

    private final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 7;
    private final String nome;
    private Trajeto[] ligacoes;

    private double minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    private double minCusto = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    private double minDuracao = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    private int num_cidades;
    private Ponto_Turistico previous;

    /**
     * Construtor de Cidade
     *
     * @param nome Nome da Cidade
     *
     */
    public Ponto_Turistico(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.ligacoes = new Trajeto[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
        this.num_cidades = 0;
    }



    /**
     * Método para comparar Pontos Turisticos
     *
     * @param other outra cidade
     * @return -1 se menor 0 igual 1 superior
     */
    public int compareTo(Ponto_Turistico other) {
        return Double.compare(minDistance, other.minDistance);
    }

    /**
     * Obter nome
     *
     * @return nome
     */
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    /**
     * Obter adjacencias
     *
     * @return array de adjacencias
     */
    public Trajeto[] getAdjacencias() {
        return ligacoes;
    }

    /**
     * obter minima distancia
     *
     * @return
     */
    public double getMinDistance() {
        return minDistance;
    }

    /**
     * Obter anterior
     *
     * @return
     */
    public Ponto_Turistico getPrevious() {
        return previous;
    }

    public void setAdjacencies(Trajeto[] adjacencies) {
        this.ligacoes = adjacencies;
    }

    public void setMinDistance(double minDistance) {
        this.minDistance = minDistance;
    }

    public void setPrevious(Ponto_Turistico previous) {
        this.previous = previous;
    }

    public int getDEFAULT_CAPACITY() {
        return DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
    }

    public int getNum_cidades() {
        return num_cidades;
    }

    public void setNum_cidades(int num_cidades) {
        this.num_cidades = num_cidades;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.num_cidades == 0;
    }

    /**
     * Expandir capacidadade de adjacencias
     *
     * @return
     */
    private Trajeto[] expandCapacity() {
        Trajeto[] novo = new Trajeto[this.ligacoes.length + DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
        System.arraycopy(novo, this.num_cidades, this.ligacoes, 0, this.num_cidades);
        return novo;
    }

    /**
     * Adiciona uma adjacencia
     *
     * @param cidadefinal cidade destino
     * @param distancia diastancia entre cidades
     * @param duracao duracao
     * @param custo custo por km
     */
    public void adicionar_trajeto(Ponto_Turistico cidadefinal, double distancia, double duracao, double custo) {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            this.ligacoes[0] = new Trajeto(cidadefinal, distancia, duracao, custo);
            this.num_cidades++;
        } else if (this.num_cidades == this.ligacoes.length) {
            this.ligacoes = expandCapacity();
            this.ligacoes[this.num_cidades] = new Trajeto(cidadefinal, distancia, duracao, custo);
            this.num_cidades++;
        } else {
            this.ligacoes[this.num_cidades] = new Trajeto(cidadefinal, distancia, duracao, custo);
            this.num_cidades++;
        }
    }

    public double getMinCusto() {
        return minCusto;
    }

    public void setMinCusto(double minCusto) {
        this.minCusto = minCusto;
    }

    public double getMinDuracao() {
        return minDuracao;
    }

    public void setMinDuracao(double minDuracao) {
        this.minDuracao = minDuracao;
    }

    /**
     * Funçao exponencial
     *
     * @param h o valor
     * @param d exponencial
     * @return resultado
     */
    private int exp(double h, double d) {
        int res = 1;
        for (double i = 0; i <= d; i++) {
            res *= h;
        }
        return res;
    }

    /**
     * Alterar adjacencia
     *
     * @param pos posição
     * @param trajeto trajeto
     */
    public void alterarTrajeto(T pos, T trajeto) {
        this.ligacoes[(Integer) pos] = (Trajeto) trajeto;
    }

}
```

**EDIT ** MAIN**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws EmptyCollectionException, IOException {
        // mark all the vertices 

        Roteiros play = new Roteiros();
        play.carregarinfo();
        play.iniciar();

    }
```

**EDIT com NOVO TESTE **

```
public class testeh{
private final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 20;
private int[] pontosTuristicos_roteiro;
private int cont_cid;


public void Roteiros() {

    this.pontosTuristicos_roteiro = new int[DEFAULT_SIZE];
    this.cont_cid = 0;

}

 public void adPontoTuristico(String pontoT) {

        if (this.cont_cid == this.pontosTuristicos_roteiro.length) {

        }
        this.pontosTuristicos_roteiro[this.cont_cid] = 0;
        this.cont_cid++;




}
```

**CLASSE MAIN **

```
 testeh dc = new testeh();
 dc.adPontoTuristico("ola");
```

Continua a dar erro, NullPointerExeption...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Desculpe a sinceridade, mas o seu código está muito cheio de problemas e bastante gambiarrado.

A causa do seu `NullPointerException` é isso:

```
public void Roteiros() {
    // ...
}
```

**Não coloque `void` na assinatura dos construtores!** Isso não é um construtor na verdade, é apenas um método com o mesmo nome da classe fingindo ser um construtor!

Além disso, seu código tem mais uma miríade de problemas. Por exemplo, isso:

```
    private Ponto_Turistico[] expandCapacity_PT() {

        Ponto_Turistico[] novo = new Ponto_Turistico[this.pontosTuristicos_roteiro.length + this.DEFAULT_SIZE];
        System.arraycopy(novo, this.cont_cid, this.pontosTuristicos_roteiro, 0, this.cont_cid);
        return novo;
    }
```

Ele cria um novo array mas não o coloca em lugar nenhum. Todos os lugares onde este método é chamado não fazem nada com o retorno. Se ao invés de usar arrays, você usasse listas, não precisaria ficar fazendo tanta gambiarra para saber se o array está cheio ou não, ou onde inserir elementos nele.

Também tem isso:

```
        if (procurarPontoTuris((T) opc) != null) { // se o ponto turistico que o jogador adicionar  for diferente  de null, ou seja se ainda nao existir

            Ponto_Turistico nova_city = new Ponto_Turistico(opc);
            adPontoTuristico((T) nova_city);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Já existe um ponto turistico com o nome escolhido!");
        }
```

Ou seja, se achou o ponto turístico, então adiciona um novo. Se não achou, diz que já existe. Você deveria ter usado `==` ao invés de `!=`.

Também, você usa os tipos genéricos para absolutamente nada útil. Tire os tipos genéricos deste código que eles não servem para nada.

Também digo para você usar apenas um `Scanner` e por favor, siga as regras de nomenclatura da linguagem. Há ainda mais um monte de coisas que eu poderia sugerir, mas vou ficar por aqui por enquanto.

Comment: Amigo, desculpe o trabalho, por um erro de porcaria!! Obrigado pelas sugestões de melhoria. Essa classe foi copiada de outra,  e muitas coisas ainda estão incompletas, mas obrigado pela correcção!

Comment: @ZéLuísDias Tudo bem.